# Sequelize node, new model instance returns string literal instead of actual value

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

When I am creating a new instance of model using `await Session.create()`, its returning the default literal, instead of the generated value.

I am getting

```
dataValues: {
 id: Literal { val: '(UUID())' },
 created_at: Literal { val: 'NOW()' },
 updated_at: Literal { val: 'NOW()' }
}
```

Instead of the generated uuid and the current date -time, the sql table has the correct values inserted but I can't get them when I use create().

Sequelize Connection:

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.SQL_DB, process.env.SQL_USER, process.env.SQL_PASSWORD,
  {
    host: process.env.SQL_HOST,
    dialect: 'mysql',
    dialectOptions: {
      multipleStatements: true
    },
    // logging: false,
  }
);
```

Model:

```
export const Session = sequelize.define(
  "session",
  {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: sequelize.literal("(UUID())"),
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    created_at: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      defaultValue: sequelize.literal("NOW()"),
    },
    updated_at: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      defaultValue: sequelize.literal("NOW()"),
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: false,
    underscored: true,
    freezeTableName: true,
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you define default values using sequelize.literal, Sequelize treats them as literal strings and doesn't execute the functions like UUID() or NOW() in the JavaScript environment. The actual execution of these functions happens at the database level when the record is inserted.

you should instead use the defaultValueproperty with a function to generate the values dynamically. Try something like this,

```js
export const Session = sequelize.define(
  "session",
  {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    created_at: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW,
    },
    updated_at: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: false,
    underscored: true,
    freezeTableName: true,
  }
)
```